# Joomla User Pofile Editing

Tags: joomla

WHy is the Joomla Profile editing showing these ?
Where can I find the setting for the Editor , Time Zone and Frontend language?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the Joomla backend, go to:

**Users** (top menu) >> **User Manager** >> **Options**

In here make sure you have **Frontend User Parameters** set to **off**